# OnChange callback for md-slider in Angular Material Design

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How can I know in controller that the value of < md-slider > from Angular Material Design has changed?

Comment: it's a standard element, use `ng-model=` to monitor it's value.  https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.slider/directive/mdSlider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't find how to do it in a proper way, but you can do it by creating a directive and an event, like:

```
.directive('testDragEnd', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('$md.dragend', function() {
                console.info('Drag Ended');
            })
        }
    }
})
```

And the, you have to add the directive in the `<md-slider>. (<md-slider test-drag-end></md-slider>).`

I hope it helps.

In Angular Material's git hub there are few other events where you can do the same:

https://github.com/angular/material/blob/952ee3489e84226c73f83db15f8586db93cdca19/src/components/slider/slider.js

```
element
      .on('keydown', keydownListener)
      .on('$md.pressdown', onPressDown)
      .on('$md.pressup', onPressUp)
      .on('$md.dragstart', onDragStart)
      .on('$md.drag', onDrag)
      .on('$md.dragend', onDragEnd);
```

Comment: This is a nice solution for the issue described here: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2060



I want to respond to changes on my slider with an HTTP request, and I only want that to happen at the end of the drag, not once for every model change.  Listening for the '$md.pressup' event seems like a good way to solve this.

Comment: The $md.pressup event you mentioned is probably more appropriate than $md.dragend.  The $md.dragend event appears only to be fired if the slider is actually drug by the user - if they click to change, and don't drag, dragend is never fired ($md.pressup is, however).  Since the OP wants to know anytime a value is changed, $md.dragend won't always work.

Answer (score 10):

you can add ng-change on the directive

```
<md-slider min="0" max="50" ng-model="text" ng-change="myMethod()" md-discrete></md-slider>
```

Comment: Works in Angular 1.6.4 with Angular Material 1.1.4

Answer (score 1):

I used a $watch on the variable bound to the slider:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function() {
        return $scope.tex;
    },
    function(newValue, oldValue) {
        $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple().content("Slider=" + newValue).position("top right").hideDelay(1500));
    });
```

In my case my HTML looked like this:

```
<md-slider min="0" max="50" ng-model="tex" md-discrete></md-slider>
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

I put a callback function in `ng-blur`, that worked for me. (Tried `ng-change` at first, but that became very slow).

Example:

```
<md-slider ng-model="gigabyte" ng-blur="myCallbackFunction()" id="myslider"> </md-slider>
<input flex type="number" ng-model="gigabyte" ng-blur="myCallbackFunction()" aria-controls="myslider">
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-mouseup` should do the trick. If you want to add logic (as I did) to ensure your value has changed before make your db call to update, you can add that inside your `saveChanges()` function inside your controller.

`<md-slider ng-mouseup="vm.saveChanges(vm.myModel)"></md-slider>`